# Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable se --allow-external install to allow)

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install pip on my windows 7 64 bit platform. when I run command : python get-pip.py install I get the following error:
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable
se --allow-external install to allow).

could you please help ...